# How to run a download command on jQuery for an audio file

Tags: javascript, browser, href

I am trying to create a download button that when it is pressed, it finds the url of the current playing song and downloads it.
The issue is when I press the button, the browser opens the file location instead of downloading it.
I know there are some settings can be done on server side to download attachment. But in this scenario I do not have access to the server.

```js
var button = $("button");
var url = "shorturl.at/cfikM";

button.on("click", function(){
   top.location.href = url;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Download</button>
```

basically i want it to work just like: `<a href="URL" download> Download </a>`

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What is the exact current behavior of that button? Does it open a new tab and lists directories? does it open a new tab and downloads some bogus file? does the button do anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is this:

Have a hidden href link that points to the file you want to download:

```
    <a style="visibility: hidden" id="lelink" href="http://some.file.url" download="w3logo">        Download me      </a>
```

Then you can use Jquery to set the button's behavior and trigger the "link-click":

```
button.on("click", function(){
   document.querySelector("#lelink").click()
})
```

Of course this will open the link contents on the same tab (acting like a redirect).

If you want the file contents to be downloaded without redirecting the tab, then this will not work

Hope this helps

Comment: The `download` attribute only works for *same origin* URLs